# (Yet Another) Conway's Game of Life in Haskell (Naive)

Tags: haskell, unit-testing, game-of-life

I code Haskell as a hobbyist. I'm interested in feedback on my naive implementation of [Conway's Game of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway's_Game_of_Life). Specifically, as stated in the Quick Tour of the website, I am interested in:

- Best practices and design pattern usage
- Correctness in unanticipated cases

Admitting the naivete of the implementation, I'm not so much interested in security issues or performance, unless my implementation is just a totally unwise implementation. That is, if I might, for example, run three iterations of a 3x3 Blinker and kill the CPU. No matter how pretty I think my code, that's just stupid.

First I list the test specifications. We don't currently use TDD at work, so I'm a bit inexperienced in TDD.

```
module Life_Spec where

import Test.Hspec
import Life

-- Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbors dies.
-- Any live cell with two or three live neighbors lives.
-- Any live cell with more than three live neighbors dies.
-- Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbors becomes live.

main :: IO ()
main = hspec $ do
  describe "Life" $ do
    it "Returns a dead cell for a live cell with fewer than two live neighbors." $
      generation (Alive, 1) `shouldBe` Dead

    it "Returns a live cell for a live cell with two or three live neighbors." $
      generation (Alive, 2) `shouldBe` Alive

    it "Returns a live cell for a live cell with two or three live neighbors." $
      generation (Alive, 3) `shouldBe` Alive

    it "Returns a dead cell for a live cell with more than three live neighbors." $
      generation (Alive, 4) `shouldBe` Dead

    it "Returns a live cell for a dead cell with more exactly three live neighbors." $
      generation (Dead, 3) `shouldBe` Alive

    it "Returns the indices of a cell's neighbors for a 3x3 grid." $
      neighbors 0 [] [Dead, Alive, Dead] [Dead, Alive, Dead] `shouldBe` [Alive, Dead, Alive]

    it "Returns an empty Grid when given an empty Grid." $
      gridGeneration (Grid []) `shouldBe` (Grid [])

    it "Successfully processes the 3x3 blinker grid." $
      gridGeneration (Grid [[Dead, Alive, Dead],
                            [Dead, Alive, Dead],
                            [Dead, Alive, Dead]]) `shouldBe` (Grid [[Dead , Dead , Dead ],
                                                                    [Alive, Alive, Alive],
                                                                    [Dead , Dead , Dead ]])

    it "Successfully processes the 5x5 blinker grid." $
      gridGeneration (Grid [[Dead, Dead, Dead , Dead, Dead],
                            [Dead, Dead, Alive, Dead, Dead],
                            [Dead, Dead, Alive, Dead, Dead],
                            [Dead, Dead, Alive, Dead, Dead],
                            [Dead, Dead, Dead , Dead, Dead]]) `shouldBe` (Grid [[Dead, Dead , Dead , Dead , Dead],
                                                                                [Dead, Dead , Dead , Dead , Dead],
                                                                                [Dead, Alive, Alive, Alive, Dead],
                                                                                [Dead, Dead , Dead , Dead , Dead],
                                                                                [Dead, Dead , Dead , Dead , Dead]])
```

Next I list my implementation:

```
module Life where

import Data.Maybe (catMaybes)

data State = Dead | Alive deriving (Eq, Show)
newtype Grid = Grid [[State]] deriving (Eq, Show)

generation :: (State, Int) -> State
generation (Alive, 2) = Alive
generation (_    , 3) = Alive
generation (_    , _) = Dead

-- Surely this can be done more cleanly...
neighbors :: Int -> [State] -> [State] -> [State] -> [State]
neighbors x rowAbove rowOfX rowBelow =
  let (w,y) = (x-1,x+1)
      cs = [w, x, y, w, y, w, x, y]
      rs = replicate 3 rowAbove ++ replicate 2 rowOfX ++ replicate 3 rowBelow
   in catMaybes . map maybeCell $ zip rs cs
  where maybeCell (r,c)
          | c < 0         = Nothing
          | c >= length r = Nothing
          | otherwise     = Just (r!!c)

gridGeneration :: Grid -> Grid
gridGeneration (Grid []) = Grid []
gridGeneration (Grid rs@(row0:row1:row2:rows)) = Grid $ g ([]:rs)
  where
    g (r0:r1:r2:rs) = [processRow r0 r1 r2] ++ g (r1:r2:rs)
    g (r0:r1:[])    = [processRow r0 r1 []]
    g  _            = []
    processRow r0 r1 r2 = reverse $ foldl p [] [0..(length r1 - 1)]
      where p a n = (generation (r1!!n, live $ neighbors n r0 r1 r2)) : a
            live = length . filter (==Alive)
gridGeneration _ = undefined
```

Comment: After staring at this for 15 minutes, I still don't understand how it works. Also, it fails (error: undefined) for grids only one or two rows, but I assume you knew that already.

Comment: Oh, after realizing that `cs` stands for columns and `rs` stands for rows, I understand that part better. Now I just need another 15 minutes to decipher the rest. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Ideomatic code

[HLint](https://github.com/ndmitchell/hlint) gave some hints,

```
catMaybes . map maybeCell <=> mapMaybe maybeCell
```

and a few superfluous brackets, but nothing big.

---

Hlint doesn't catch some other unnecessarily convoluted formulations though:

```
reverse $ foldl p [] someList
p a n = f n : a
```

In Haskell, `foldl` is usually *less* efficient than `foldr` due to laziness. (In some cases you want to use the strict version `foldl'`, but almost never `foldl`.)

```
foldr p [] someList
p n a = f n : a
```

And this is completely equivalent to:

```
map p someList
p n = f n
```

---

Another example: Using a tuple instead of just two values as arguments to `generation`. This is not wrong, just unideomatic and doesn't serve any purpose (as far as I can see).

```
generation :: (State, Int) -> State
why not use
generation :: State -> Int -> State
```

## Formatting

You can use formatting to emphasize structure:

```
cols  = [w, x, y,
         w,    y,
         w, x, y]
```

Use clear names

## Testing

Your tests looks good, you might want to add cases for smaller grids and non-square ones as well though. You might also consider if QuickCheck could be helpful, but I don't see any obvious properties, apart from that all functions should preserve length, but that is already (mostly) covered by the existing tests.

Thanks for supplying tests, it helped me with verifying that my suggestions didn't break anything. :)

Edit: According to Hspec documentation you are supposed to use one `describe` per function, not one per module as you did.

## Edge cases

As I said, you crash on grids with one or two rows, but your code actually
supports them already (they are handled by `g`). Just remove the arbitrary constraint of needing at least
three rows at the second case of `gridGeneration` (and remove the third case).

```
gridGeneration (Grid rs) = Grid $ g ([]:rs)
  where
    ...
```

The function `g` also handles empty grids correctly, so you can remove the first case as well.

## Efficiency

I know you weren't that interested in efficiency, but here it is anyways.

Your code currently traverses the whole row for every single cell. Example:

```
neighbors 0 [] [] $ repeat [Dead]
```

Will never terminate, despite not really needing anything other than the first value

---

A good rule of thumb is that if you are indexing over lists, you're probably doing something wrong. And if you are iterating over all indexes of a list, you're definitely doing something wrong.

Either use a different data structure or a different method. In the latter case, you could probably just use a fold or a map.

In your case it is not as simple as that, but you can reuse (read "factor out as a function") the pattern you used for traversing the neighboring rows, but for the columns.

## Misc points

You can loosen up the types of some functions, without changing any other code, like `neighbors`:

```
neighbors :: Int -> [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

This may or may not be better, but it's good to know, so you can factor out more generic functions and just keep the specific ones with the code.

## My version

Without changing anything but formatting, names, adding type signatures and replacing equivalent constructs:

```
module Life where

import Data.Maybe (mapMaybe)

data State = Dead | Alive deriving (Eq, Show)
newtype Grid = Grid [[State]] deriving (Eq, Show)

gridGeneration :: Grid -> Grid
gridGeneration (Grid rs) = Grid $ g ([]:rs)
  where
    g (r0:r1:r2:rs) = processRow r0 r1 r2 : g (r1:r2:rs)
    g [r0,r1]       = [processRow r0 r1 []]
    g  _            = []


processRow :: [State] -> [State] -> [State] -> [State]
processRow r0 r1 r2 = map updateCell [0..(length r1 - 1)]
  where
    updateCell n = generation (r1 !! n) (live $ neighbors n r0 r1 r2)
    live         = length . filter (==Alive)

neighbors :: Int -> [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
neighbors x rowAbove rowOfX rowBelow = mapMaybe maybeCell $ zip rows cols
  where
    (w,y) = (x-1,x+1)
    cols  = [w, x, y, -- Use formatting to indicate structure
             w,    y,
             w, x, y]
    rows  = replicate 3 rowAbove ++
            replicate 2 rowOfX   ++
            replicate 3 rowBelow

    maybeCell :: ([a], Int) -> Maybe a
    maybeCell (r, idx)
      | idx < 0         = Nothing
      | idx >= length r = Nothing
      | otherwise       = Just (r !! idx)

generation :: State -> Int -> State
generation Alive 2 = Alive
generation _     3 = Alive
generation _     _ = Dead
```

---

Update 1:

## With new algorithm

I also remade the code with using the same method for traversing both rows and columns. I factored out the function `g` as `map3` and added the padding first, to simplify things. Then I used `zip3` to encapsulate the three lists, so I could `map3` over them again.

```
module Life where

import Data.List (zip3)

data State = Dead | Alive deriving (Eq, Show)
newtype Grid = Grid [[State]] deriving (Eq, Show)

gridGeneration :: Grid -> Grid
gridGeneration (Grid rs) = Grid $ map3 processRow (withEmptyRows . map withEmptyCols $ rs)
  where
    emptyRow = repeat Dead
    withEmptyCols xs = Dead : xs ++ [Dead]
    withEmptyRows xss = emptyRow : xss ++ [emptyRow]


-- Map a function over each triplet of neighbouring values
map3 :: (a -> a -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map3 f (x0:x1:x2:xs) = f x0 x1 x2 : map3 f (x1:x2:xs)
map3 f _             = []

processRow :: [State] -> [State] -> [State] -> [State]
processRow r0 r1 r2 = map updateCell . map3 neighbors $ rows
  where
    rows :: [(State,State,State)]
    rows = zip3 r0 r1 r2

    updateCell (cell, neighs)  = generation cell (live neighs)
    live  = length . filter (==Alive)

neighbors :: (a,a,a) -> (a,a,a) -> (a,a,a) -> (a,[a])
neighbors (x1,x2,x3)
          (x4,x5,x6)
          (x7,x8,x9) = (x5, [x1,x2,x3,
                             x4,   x6,
                             x7,x8,x9])

generation :: State -> Int -> State
generation Alive 2 = Alive
generation _     3 = Alive
generation _     _ = Dead
```

---

Update 2:

Here is a Hspec for `map3`, using QuickCheck:

```
  describe "Life.map3" $ do
    it "Decreases the length of the list by two, but not to a negative length" $
      property $ \xs -> length (map3 f xs) === 0 `max` (length xs - 2)
        where f () () () = ()
```

The fact that the type is completely generic (`map3 :: (a->a->a->b)->[a]->[b]`) means that it cannot do anything with the values, so we don't have to test for that.

Comment: We're not supposed to use comments for thanks, so I'll elaborate on my thanks: this is *exactly* the kind of feedback I was hoping for! So thank you so much!